# No such file or directory after rpm -e --nodeps packagename instead of command not found

Tags: ssh, yum, rpm, remove

I installed `ethtool` using `yum install ethtool` and then removed it using `rpm -e --nodeps ethtool` because when I tried to remove `ethtool` with `yum` it was going to remove a bunch of important dependencies like `php`, `httpd`, `etc`.

When I run any command which shouldn't exist such as `fakecommand` I get this message:

```
[root@test sbin]# fakecommand
-bash: fakecommand: command not found
[root@test sbin]#
```

However, when trying to run `ethtool` after removing it with `rpm -e --nodeps ethtool` I get `No such file or directory` instead of `No such file or directory`:

```
[root@test sbin]# ethtool
-bash: /sbin/ethtool: No such file or directory
[root@test sbin]#
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, all you have to do is restart the ssh connection. Turns out, it was just a client-sided cache.

Comment: Specifically, from the man page: "[b]ash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files. `hash -r` would have fixed the problem as well.